# display span class in after set time

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to achieve is using javascript display both these spans after five seconds for the first one and 10 seconds for the second one.

```
<span class="5-seconds">Connecting...</span>
<span class="10-seconds">Connection Established<span>
```

unsure on how I would achieve this just using javascript thank-you for the help.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: I think that my solution is better, check it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SetTimeout

Here,initially i made both spans to display:none,5seconds after html is completely rendered im showing up first div and after 10seconds second div is shown

```js
window.onload = function() {
  ShowSpans('first', 5);
  ShowSpans('second', 10);
}


function ShowSpans(classname, time) {
  setTimeout(function() {

    document.getElementsByClassName(classname)[0].style.display = "block";
  }, time * 1000);

}
```

```css
span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="first">Connecting...</span>
<span class="second">Connection Established<span>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("x").className = "hidden";
  document.getElementById('y').style.display = 'block';
}, 5000);
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('y').style.display = 'none';
}, 10000);
```

```css
.fiveSeconds {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.tenSeconds {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: none;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='x' class='fiveSeconds'>Connecting...</div>
<div id='y' class='tenSeconds'>Connected!</div>
```